# How to groupby two columns while assigning 'aggregated' columns to new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-handling

I'm using Python, and I need to "aggregate" on the columns "R" then "J", so that for each R, each row is a unique "J".

I don't want to lose the data in C, so I need to create new columns named C1 for T=1, C2 for T=2, and C2 for T=3, that writes in the corresponding data from C to C1, C2, or C3 using T.

So I need to go from:

```
#______________            _______________________________
#| R  J  T  C |           |# R  J  C(T=1)  C(T=2)  C(T=3)|
#| a  1  1  x |           |# a  1    x        y       z  |
#| a  1  2  y |           |# b  1    w                   |  
#| a  1  3  z |  ----->   |# b  2    v                   | 
#| b  1  1  w |           |# b  3    s                   |
#| b  2  1  v |           |# c  1    t        r          |
#| b  3  1  s |           |# c  2    u                   |
#| c  1  1  t |           |______________________________|
#| c  1  2  r |           
#| c  2  1  u |
#|____________|

data = {'R': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 
        'J': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2], 
        'T': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], 
        'C': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'v', 's', 't', 'r', 'u'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

PS. If it helps, columns J and T both have an extra column with unique IDs.

```
J_ID = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6]
T_ID = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the data as code so people can paste into their IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use groupby, and then convert the C column as a list then Series.

```
(
    df.groupby(['R','J'])
    .apply(lambda x: x.C.tolist()).apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns=lambda x: f'C{x+1}')
    .reset_index()
)


    R   J   C1  C2  C3
0   a   1   x   y   z
1   b   1   w   NaN NaN
2   b   2   v   NaN NaN
3   b   3   s   NaN NaN
4   c   1   t   r   NaN
5   c   2   u   NaN NaN
```

Comment: There is room for performance enhancement at the expense of simplicity if the OP has a large dataset.

Comment: It's a shame `explode` doesn't take an argument whether to explode along rows or columns.

Comment: @Allen This definitely did solve the problem I presented. My dataset happens to be small enough for solution, but it does have more columns than what I showed. So what if each R had some columns with characteristics (same values for each R) and there were more than one column like C that would need the same treatment as C?